# Extract all odd numbers from numpy array

Tags: numpy

how can i extract all the odd number from a numpy array?

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,9])
a[a % 2 == 1]
```

Out[13]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 9])

Answer (score 1):

```
b = np.where(a%2)
print(f'Array with Odd Numbers: {a[b]}')
```

Here a is the array containing all the numbers.
And the Output of Odd Numbers from that array is given as a[b]